# globally accessing input from html file for different functions in JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a basic calculator in my html page that i input two numbers and when i click on the buttons assigned to add,subtract, multiply or divide i call different functions in JS linked externally to perform those operations and the problem is that on every function on the JS code i have to get values from the html file individually which is redundant so I want that i only get values from the HTML document once and the values work for all the functions defined in JS

I expect that when i click on the buttons the functions are called and want to access the values of the numbers from the HTML once in the JS file which  works for all the functions defined in JS but i didn't know what to exactly do for it so I had to access the values individually in all functions which is definitely not what i want

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
  <script src="calculate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px" align="center">
      <label>First Number</label><input type="text" id="num1" name="" onblur="access_1()"><br>
      <label>Second Number </label><input type="text" id="num2" onblur="access_2()"><br>
      <button onclick="add();">Add</button>
      <button onclick="subtract();">Subtract</button>
      <button onclick="multiply();">Multiply </button>
      <button onclick="divide();">Divide </button>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JS for the operations

```
function access_1(){
    let num1= document.getElementById('num1').value;
}
function access_2(){
    let num2= document.getElementById('num2').value;
}

function add(num1,num2){
    alert(`${num1} & ${num2}`)
    // let result=num1+num2;
    // alert(`The sum is ${result}`);
}

function subtract(num1,num2){
    let result=num1-num2;
    alert(`The difference is ${result}`);
}

function multiply(num1,num2){
    let result=num1*num2;
    alert(`The product is ${result}`);
}

function divide(num1,num2){
    let result=num1/num2;
    alert(`The quotient is ${result}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code, or create a codepen of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is scope.

When the onblur functions access_1 or access_2 are called, they create variables that are immediately discarded when the function returns. You cannot access them from anywhere outside this function.

The quickest fix to your problem would be to declare num1 and num2 outside of your function and then just access them from within.

```
let num1, num2;

function access_1() {
    num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
}

function access_2() {
    num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
}
```

Comment: the problem is i have to declare num1 and num2 on every function add,subtract,multiply and divide which is becoming reduntant so i am wondering if there is a way that i enter num1 and num2 and i only have to access these values from JS once and the numbers are carried onto for the functions

Comment: can't edit my answer somehow, hit me up on discord if you want to go through this together. penny#2062